# NSIS Installer showing HTML Dialog

Tags: html, nsis

Is there a way to show my users a HTML content within the UI of the installer?

Without me writing my own UI for each of the dialogs?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [nsWeb-plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsWeb_plug-in), it might fill your needs.

Answer (score 1):

"HTML Dialog" and "HTML content" are different things. You can embed a browser with `nsweb-plugin` to show content (a license text, ads...) but it behaves like a black box. If you want to show some kind of form and read user input, then you'll need the html page sends input data to a server, and your nsis installer queries that remote server. Not trivial, although do-able.